# Library and client app configuration for webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to create proper webpack setup for developing my own react component and demo app for that library.

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── component.dist.js
├── demo
│   ├── demo.js
│   ├── app.js
│   └── index.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── component.source.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

And I would like to setup webpack so that it handles building `component.source.js` from `src` directory to `component.dist.js` in `build`. This was the easy part. In addition I would like to have demo application (`demo.js`) for my component. This demo app requires dist version of my component (`component.dist.js`) and `react`. Webpack should take `demo.js` and output bundle to `app.js` which then I use in script tag in `index.html`.

I don't know hot to setup webpack and webpack-dev-server with hot-reloading to properly handle this case. What I've tried:

1. Using webpack-dev-server, but I don't know how to import/require `component.dist.js` in `demo.js` because dev-server keep bundles in memory. I've tried using `output.publicPath` but apparently it takes effect only in html pages, not in js files.
2. Using webpack with `--watch` option. In that case when demo app is being built there is an error from `demo.js` that `component.dist` cannot be resolved.

Comment: Why you dont want to build demo.js and component.source.js at the same time?

Comment: It could be at the same time - it's ok. But I'm not quite sure how to do it properly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing two builds? one for component.dist.js and another for app.js. is it possible that you could simple require component.source.js from your demo.js, since this file is always available, and have demo.js as your entry, and app.js as your output.
you can setup hot realoading using react-hot-loader

Comment: Actually requiring `component.source.js` instead of `component.dist.js` is so far the only way I've managed to set everything up correctly. On the other hand requiring `component.dist.js` seems more like the right way for me since any app using my component will be doing this that way.

Comment: Try this. Run wepback to bundle component.dist.js first before firing up webpack dev server for you demo. If you are using node, you could do a script and have the && operator so it always execute the first script first and after finishing then fire up the dev server.
On top of that, have a simple task runner(maybe gulp), that would watch and build your component.dist.js on change of component.source.js. if you plan to alter this file while working with demo.js

then you can require component.dist.js on demo.js